# Don't understand second parameter .replace() string method

Tags: javascript

I don't understand what the "chr" represents or is in this function. I understand that "match" must represent every character in the string that matched to the regex and the "chr" must be something that's used to determine weather each character is uppercase or lowercase but I don't know how it works or how it determines true/false values.

```
let swapcase = str => {
  return str.replace(/([a-z]+)|([A-Z]+)/g, (match, chr) => {
    if (chr) {
      return match.toUpperCase()
    } else {
      return match.toLowerCase()
    }
  })
}
console.log(swapcase('DdishDJSK')) // logs dDISHdjsk
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter

Comment: There are two different capturing groups in the regular expression. `chr` only refers to the capturing group used for lowercase characters.

Comment: `str.replace(/[a-z]/ig, c => String.fromCharCode(c.charCodeAt(0) ^ 0x20));` would be equivalent.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts True, but depending on the details of ASCII encodings like that is poor style.

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression:

```
/([a-z]+)|([A-Z]+)/g
```

is made of two "components" (in parentheses), and each string matched can either be a match for the first, or the second component.

`chr` here refers to whatever is matched by the first component, i.e. if your string happened to match the first component, `chr` will be equal to your string. Otherwise it will evaluate to `undefined`.

In your specific case, this means that if your match is lowercase, `chr` will be equal to this match and therefore `if(chr)` will resolve to `true`. If your match is uppercase, `chr` will be undefined and `if(chr)` will resolve to `false`.

Comment: FYI, the "components" are normally called "capture groups".

Comment: So does this mean that if there were a third parameter after 'chr' it would refer to the second component or capture group of the regular expression?

Comment: @NicoFederico Yes, exactly.